# exceptionListener and errorHandler in apache camle jms component, not working for me

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I am connecting to IBM MQ using apache camel Jms component using below code and configuration. When MQ manager goes down by any reason while message polling or is down at the time of camel route startup, my errorHandler or exceptionListener is not invoked.

```
jmsComponenet = JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge((ConnectionFactory) obj);
camelContext.addComponent("ibm-mq", jmsComponenet);
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("ibm-mq:queue:PE_OUTBOUND?concurrentConsumers=5&exceptionListener=#exceptionListener&errorHandler=#errorHandler").to(
                            "mqprocessor"); 
   }

});
```

Spring Application-Context :

```
<bean id="exceptionListener" class="com.*****.JMSExceptionListener" />
<bean id="errorHandler" class="com.*****.JMSConnectionErrorHandler" />
```

The classess implements required interface

`javax.jms.ExceptionListener` and `org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler`

Despite of specifying Handler and Listener still MQ Connection error is just logged as WARN message in log and controll do not reach these classes.

I am missing / doing anything incorrect here?

Here is DEBUG log -

```
11:18:20,783 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorHandler'
11:18:20,784 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Configured property: errorHandler on bean: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration@17b86db4 with value: com.manh.processors.JMSConnectionErrorHandler@4d2a5096
11:18:20,784 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'exceptionListener'
11:18:20,784 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Configured property: exceptionListener on bean: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration@17b86db4 with value: com.manh.processors.JMSExceptionListener@6c8b8e49
11:18:20,785 DEBUG [org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) ibm-mq://queue:PE_OUTBOUND?concurrentConsumers=5&errorHandler=%23errorHandler&exceptionListener=%23exceptionListener converted to endpoint: Endpoint[ibm-mq://queue:PE_OUTBOUND?concurrentConsumers=5&errorHandler=%23errorHandler&exceptionListener=%23exceptionListener] by component: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent@fb03c67
11:18:20,785 TRACE [org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementLifecycleStrategy] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Checking whether to register Endpoint[ibm-mq://queue:PE_OUTBOUND?concurrentConsumers=5&errorHandler=%23errorHandler&exceptionListener=%23exceptionListener] from route: null
```

Answer (score 2):

default testConnectionOnStartup = false. I set it to ture and got exception on startup of route.

ErrorHandler come into play only if exception occurs while processing of message.

Thank you for the help Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Logging with a warn message is default when an error handler cannot be found, so I suspect Camel is not able to find an instance of the provided bean. Try setting the camel log level to debug and see what it says when the route is started, I would expect some kind of message saying that the referenced beans cannot be found.

Comment: I don not see any bean reference error in log. I see **Configured property: errorHandler** and **Configured property: exceptionListener** configuration as expected in log. I have added full log above in question section.

Comment: What does the actual WARN message look like?

Comment: 14:30:51,249 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer] (Camel (CamelContext) thread #3 - JmsConsumer[PE_OUTBOUND]) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'PE_OUTBOUND' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'PE_OUTBOUND'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2202' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_QUIESCING').:

Comment: The errorhandler and exceptionhandler is specific to your route. I have a feeling that your exception is thrown before the actual route is invoked, which is why your specified handlers never gets invoked.

Comment: default testConnectionOnStartup = false. I set it to ture and got exception on startup of route. 

ErrorHandler come into play only if exception occurs while processing of message.

Thank you for the help Daniel.